# As it is appears here, how many constants do you see in $2x^3 + y^4 = \sqrt 5$?

Tags: algebra

My original phrasing was "how many constants are there in...". I am trying to determine if this is more clear. This is not intended for an exam, just a basic question to get intro-level algebra students thinking about the difference between variables and constants.  Thank you.

Comment: I would say 4 constants (although there is only 1 *constant term*). It of course depends on your definition of "constant". My answer 4 is from a programmer's perspective, where "constant" is roughly the same as "literal". That expression has 4 literal integers.

Comment: @JohnColeman, you should post your comment as an answer.

Comment: @JoelReyesNoche in many ways my comment it too obvious to post. Dirk Liebhold has already posted an answer which contains the most important thing, that it depends on the definition of "constant".

Comment: If you are discussing the concept of a polynomial equation, you may say: the three constants in that equation are $2$, $1$, and $\sqrt{5}$.

Comment: Why not 3 and 4?

Comment: @Michael: in the context of *polynomial equations*, $3$ and $4$ would be considered names or labels for terms rather than constants.

Comment: Perhaps the word to use here is "coefficients", rather than "constants"?

Comment: I want to count the coefficients, the exponents, and the constant term.

Comment: Michael, if that is what you want, then you should say so, and not "how many constants are there".

Comment: As always, it depends on the definitions in use. Perhaps it would be helpful to include those in the question?

Comment: "... a basic question to get intro-level algebra students thinking about the difference between variables and constants". I would say that this is a really bad example and it is not "basic". Such example/question is more confusing than enlightening. "Variables" and "constants" are meaningless *without* contexts.

Comment: You look at the equation, you count the numbers and you are done. There are 4 constants. You look at the x and y, those are 2 variables. To a beginner, this has 4 constants and two variables. No in-depth defining of context is necessary. No esoteric quibbling necessary.  Visual distinguishing between x and y and digits is all you need. 

2 is always 2. x varies. y varies. 3 is always 3. 4 is always 4.  I am honestly surprised at the attempts to complicate this situation. .

Comment: Definition of "constant"- a symbol that represents an unchanging quantity.

Comment: @Michael  Everyone is saying this question is ambiguous, and I agree.  Unless you have some precise definition of a "constant" you are using in your course, this question will be impossible to answer.  Personally, I see one coefficient (2) another hidden coefficient (1), two exponents (3 and 4), two variables ($x$ and $y$), and one constant ($\sqrt{5}$).

Comment: @StevenGubkin Do you consider coefficients to be separate from constants ? Also, I personally interpret this question literally. I consider "How many constant terms are there?" to be a separate question with a separate answer.

Comment: I agree the question has ambiguities, but I don't care how many people tell me "x" and "y" could be constants, for basic intro-level math students this is the wrong thought process.

Comment: I think that different people have very different conventions as to how they use language.  You already have all the feedback you need:  most mathematicians and math educators on this site think the question is ambiguous.

Comment: Should having standards for language and conventions be a goal of math educators?

Comment: If the equation was $2x^3+y^4=\sqrt[3]{5}$, would you say it has 5 constants?

Comment: Or what about $3\times 10^4$, would that have 3 constants?

Comment: @Michael  I think that you need to pick your battles carefully.  We should certainly train our students to use language carefully:  this includes specifying which definition you are using if no definition is standard.  In some cases, where there is no consensus, you can establish a convention for your class.  You should let the students know this is just your convention, and there is no standard.  I would only do this if a fine distinction is really important to the theory you are developing.  If the precise definition of "a constant" is not that important in your course, let it slide.

Comment: As I've explained, the only thing I want my students to recognize is some things in equations represent changing quantities and some things don't. This question isn't something I would continually harp on. It is a basic question to get them thinking, and honestly is one that I've learned from through people's responses. I want my students to have a basic amount of numeric literacy, something that the United States is severely lacking. We have a serious math education problem.

Comment: @JoelReyesNoche yes and yes. In the second example you are using 3 constants to define a single quantity.

Answer (score 7):

The question

> As it is appears here, how many constants do you see in $2x^3+y^4=\sqrt{5}$?

is quite vague.  For example, are we to consider $x$ and $y$ as variables?  Or perhaps they are also constants?

There is also a problem with "invisible" constants.  For example, a quadratic equation is often defined as an equation of the form $ax^2+bx+c=0$, where $x$ is a variable and $a$, $b$, and $c$ are constants.  $x^2-x=0$ is a quadratic equation, and one can argue that it has three constants: $a=1,b=-1,c=0$.  (Or it could have four constants if we consider the $0$ at the right hand side of the equation.)  Perhaps your equation has some "invisible" constants that should also be included in the count?

Let me also repeat John Coleman's comment:

> I would say 4 constants (although there is only 1 *constant term*). It of course depends on your definition of "constant". My answer 4 is from a programmer's perspective, where "constant" is roughly the same as "literal". That expression has 4 literal integers.

In short, I feel that your question is too vague if it is to be intended to be asked by a teacher in, say, an exam.

Comment: Such a question could be good to ask *because* it is vague, if the intention is to generate discussion which leads to the teacher pointing out the need to define your terms.

Comment: Does any math teacher ever use x and y as constants? I realize that is possible, but in the United States I have never seen that. 

I just included this question on a first day handout. I thought it was an easy question. I was thinking the answer was 4.

Comment: @JohnColeman, yes, of course.  Thank you for pointing that out.

Comment: @Michael, some "letters" are usually treated as constants.  For example, $e$ (the base of the natural logarithm) or $c$ (the speed of light in a vacuum).  But I agree with you that $x$ and $y$ are seldom used as constants.

Comment: yes, "e" is an extremely well-known and universal constant.

Comment: Also, regarding "invisible constants", the question specifically asks for what you see. If anything is "invisible", it isn't counted according to the directions of the question.

Comment: Question: in $2x+3=0$, $x$ is in some regards constant (because it is $-3/2$), but does the fact that it is "an unknown" disqualify it? Or can we have "unknown constants"? :)

Comment: I have never heard the phrase "unknown constant" and not sure what the point of bringing that up is. The fact that you can solve for x doesn't change the idea that the symbol "x" is used to represent different quantities.

Answer (score 2):

The question is too ambiguous to be answered unequivocally, at almost all possible levels of sophistication. As in other answers and comments: from one viewpoint there are visibly 4 "literals", which might be what is intended by "constant". From another viewpoint, "x" and "y" might be names for constants, we have no idea. The fact that more than a single pair of possible values for x,y satisfy the equation does not give us any actual information about what they refer to. For that matter, for all we know the asserted equation is *false*... (this is possible because it is easily possible to make grammatically correct but factually false assertions). In a related vein, a problem is that the expression "$... = \sqrt{5}$" has two "free" "variables" (in a logic sense), $x$ and $y$. And so on.

Comment: At no point ever in math education in America have I seen x and y used as constants.

Comment: @Michael, ok, but how is one to _know_ that they are "not constants"? As opposed to single-letter names earlier in the alphabet? Sure, there are conventions, but conventions are not "rules", and are not innate facts of mathematics. Hence, I'd not ask this kind of question, since it is far more about convention than mathematical realities.

Comment: And, @Michael, in a situation like $x+1=3$, is $x$ a variable, or a constant? Or, if the answer is "it's an unknown", is it an unknown constant, or... what? :) Lotta potential trouble here, which has little to do with mathematics.

Comment: I understand they could be. Like I said, I am teaching math to people that struggle with almost everything.  (What the difference is between an equation and an expression. That sort of thing.) I do not have the time to go into what is possible. We use convention, as do basically all lower-level math classes in the United States.

Comment: I would call that a variable that is equal to 2 for that particular application. Next time you see "x" it might be equal to 7. And the next time the square root of 5. The value of it varies.

Comment: @Michael, I understand that it is infeasible to give serious explanations of the syntax versus semantics versus underlying reality... but, at the same time, even if the people can't precisely enunciate their (possibly subliminal) confusion about "(the conventions of) mathematics", in my observation their uneasiness is reasonably grounded in (correctly) feeling an element of whimsicality and inexplicableness in these conventions. When I've taught semi-remedial courses for people returning to college, I first try to convince them to trust their own instincts... as opposed to thinking [cont'd]

Comment: [cont'd] they've entered an alien world where nothing makes sense, and is disconnected from their experience, or from their own use of language.

Comment: That is, to be clear, I try to validate or legitimize the students' intellectual sensibilities, even if there is room for improvement. I do the same thing with grad students in mathematics: try to cajole them into a transition from their way of thinking (and possibly information base) into a more effective one, that can cope with more things than could their previous. But/and it's not that they were "wrong", but that there's a more effective viewpoint. (Not "morally" more effective, but technically/mathematically...)

Comment: @Michael: Regarding "*At no point ever in math education in America have I seen x and y used as constants*, what about labeling specific points in geometry as $x$ and $y?$ For example, the vertices of Triangle $T$ are $x,$ $y,$ and $z.$

Comment: There is also an implied coefficient of $1$ for the $y^4$.

Comment: The question asks you to state what you see. Anything implied, invisible, or could be added to create an equivalent expression is not requested to be considered.

Comment: @DaveLRenfro In your example those appear to be labels. They don't represent quantities at all. They are names. Nobody would confuse whether those were variables or constants. No definition of anything is needed. No context needed.

Comment: As @DaveLRenfro comments, "labels" are another use. But/and what is a "quantity", anyway? What is a "name"? Yes, a lot of serious people could reasonable wonder whether they were "variables" or "constants". (For that matter, it is doubtful that there is a rigorous-but-elementary "definition" of "variable".) And I would claim that context is needed. Also, it is important to know what is implicit (e.g., a coefficient of "1"). So, to "what do I see?", the answer is "it depends".

Answer (score 1):

As the term "constant" is mostly used in polynomials, I would look at this equation as the polynomial
$$2x^3 + y^4 - \sqrt{5} \in \mathbb{R}[x,y].$$
Thus, there is exactly one constant, the $\sqrt{5}$.
Depending on your definition, the number could of course differ.

However, I can't really see how this has something to do with mathematical education, care to explain?

Comment: The idea of "what is a constant?" is one I want my students to understand. This is a question trying to get them to think about that. I'm not sure how this could not be related to math education.

Comment: You are not asking about education, but rather about how many constants there are. If you are asking if this is a good question to allow your students to learn the concept of "constant", then this would be a question related to mathEdu (and my personal opinion would be "no"). As it is now, the question above is just an equation and a question that is missing a proper definition and clarification of the term "constant".

Comment: "If you are asking if this is a good question to allow your students to learn the concept of "constant " - this is more or less what I am trying to do, but I want to see how people respond to this question instead of asking them to evaluate the question itself. " a question related to mathEdu (and my personal opinion would be "no")." ---I don't get what you mean here. I don't know what MathEdu is referring to, or what question you are answering with your "no"- Maybe I am in the wrong place for this. Thank you for your input.

Comment: @Michael "I want to see how people respond to this question" -- which people? If your interest is on how *students* would respond to this question, then you are asking people in the wrong population (math educators rather than students). Furthermore, only some math educators are members of this community and only some members of this community will respond. You have two layers of self-selection bias on what is possibly the wrong population. How will such an answer really help?

Comment: Any people. I am trying to determine if this phrasing is more clear. Even a sample with self-selection bias could be useful in this regard. Most of life consists of collecting data in this manner.